# Is spark s3n support endpoint similar to s3a

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have endpoint server that is working fine for s3a filesystem in spark now I want to support `s3n://` and `s3://`

Anyone have any suggestion to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Nobody needs to set the fs.s3X.impl for any value of X. It's predefined in the core-default.xml file in hadoop-common. This rule "you have to declare it" is just some superstition passed down by people who have never tried anything different.
2. S3n was already obsolete by the time hadoop-2.7 shipped (usually the version bundled in Spark), and has had no maintenance whatsoever since hadoop-2.6 was released. It's been removed from the most recent versions as everyone is expected to have migrated.
3. It has fundamental limitations, including

   - atrocious handling of `seek()` operations on large files (the underlying library now reads to the end of the file on every backwards seek. This kills performance on columnar ORC/Parquet data.
   - no support for the v4 authentication protocol, so no support for AWS frankfurt, Seoul, London &c.
   - no support for encryption
   - no support for recovery of transient failures
   - no support for parallelized and incremental uploads of large files. S3A writes files a block at a time while the output is still being generated

Because of these issues and the fact it obsolete, all bugs filed related to s3n on the ASF JIRA are closed as WONTFIX.

Just step from s3n, move to s3a. Your life will be better.

Do know that as you use s3a, the version of the AWS libraries and all hadoop-* JARs must be in sync. the hadoop-* JARs rely on each other being synchronized, and the aws-* JARs are brittle enough over time that hadoop needs serious retesting on every upgrade, often changes in the APIs, bugs filed against the AWS SDK team, etc. Mixing things will only create unusual stack traces, which are closed as INVALID: "don't do that then".

Now, if you really want to test s3n support,

1. check out the [hadoop source tree](https://github.com/apache/hadoop) for the version of hadoop you want spark to run with
2. Follow the [testing instructions](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/testing.html) for testing s3a & s3n against your endpoint.
3. Especially the bit for [testing against non-AWS S3 services](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/testing.html#Testing_against_non_AWS_S3_endpoints.).
4. For the best s3a testing, check out hadoop trunk and run those tests too.

As noted, problems with s3n won't be fixed. Your homework. S3A ones, maybe, but you'll have to show it is a fault on the s3a libraries itself.

Answer (score 0):

Question : Is spark s3n support endpoint similar to s3a ?

Answer : Yes.

The below are the classes you need to provide in the configuration which are coming from `hadoop-aws.jar`.

```
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem, org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem
```

**Declarative way :**

In core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.s3n.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
</property>
```

or you can set them programmatically like below..

**Programatic way :**

Example :

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "AccessKey")
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "SecretKey")
```

similary for s3:// also.

hadoop-aws.jar has these classes so you need to provide the jar to your spark-submit job using...

```
--jars /usr/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar
```

Further reading [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Dependencies)

Comment: I'm aware of this , I was looking similar to this property ( fs.s3a.endpoint) for s3:// and s3n

Answer (score 0):

I have found below properties in spark to set endpoint for s3n and s3 and these works for me 
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.endpoint=http://endpoint_host:port
spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.endpoint=http://endpoint_host:port